# Creating Google Form with many list options

Tags: google-forms

I am creating a dropdown list in Google Forms, and have approximately 300 options that my users can choose from. Is there an efficient way to add the options to the Google Form as opposed to manually typing in 300 options on the backend?

Comment: i guess :( sadly you have to type all the options manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use copy & paste <sup>1</sup>.

**Reference**
<sup>1</sup>: [Quick tip: Copy and paste a list into Google Forms](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleDrive/posts/Rog4LBNc6d8), Google Drive G+ page.